# VBA SumIf with multiple search conditions

Tags: vba, excel, sumifs

I've got a small VBA code that searches column 3 of Sheet1 for the phrase "Rec", sums the corresponding values in column 4, and places the sum in another sheet.  Works great and is the following:

```
Sub SumIf()
Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
  Application.SumIf(Sheet1.Columns(3), "Rec", Sheet1.Columns(4))
End Sub
```

I now want it to incorporate another search criteria if possible--sum column 4 IF column 3 = "Rec" and column 5 ="UNK".

I've looked around a bit and haven't found much helpful/relevant info.  Is it possible to have two search conditions in one SumIf? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Use `=SUMIFS` for multiple criteria. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996167/sumifs-in-vba-with-multiple-string-criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUMIFS`
 The syntax is bit different first the sum range , then the criteria range and then the criteria..

```
Application.SumIfs(Sheet1.Columns(4), Sheet1.Columns(3), "Rec", Sheet1.Columns(5), "UNK")
```

Comment: Willarci3, At Your Call!